# Read file into line delimited array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using the 32-bit version of PowerShell and running it via the PowerGUI Script Editor.

Everything online seems to think that `Get-Content` returns the file as an array; however,

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path $xmlFilename
Write-Host $lines.GetType()
```

outputs

```
System.String
```

I know how to do this using the builtin .Net types; is there a PoweShell v2.0 way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that $xmlFilename file have more than one line separed by `n or `r`n?

if the file contain just a single line you can do it:

```
 $lines = @(Get-Content -Path $xmlFilename) # this return [object[]] type
```

or

```
$lines = ,(Get-Content -Path $xmlFilename)
```

or

```
 $lines = [string[]](Get-Content -Path $xmlFilename) # this return [string[]] type
```

Comment: I may not have been clear.  The code in my question is returning  string currently, which is not what I want.  I want an array with 1 entry per line in the file.

Comment: @Fred Are you sure that $xmlFilename file have more than one line separed by  n or rn?

Comment: That was the problem C.B., can't believe I didn't think of that.  I had opened it up in IE, which autoformats.  Opening it up in notepad++ tells a different story...  If you want to create an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Fred Edit one more time my original answer ;)