# Powershell Get-Content acts differently, depending on line count

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

something's wrong with my get-content cmdlet and I don't understand why its acting that way. I'm sure someone can help me.

I have two text files. $file1 and $file2. Both files have content or not. i read them as follows:

```
$content = get-content $File1
$content = $content + (Get-Content $File2)
```

Now lets say, $file1 has 3 lines and $file2 has 4 lines. 
echo $conent shows me 7 lines. Good.
Lets say $file1 has 1 line and $file2 has 3 lines.
echo $conent shows me 4 lines. Good too.

But, when I do

```
foreach ($i in $content)
```

it gets interessting. In example 1 the foreach loop runs 7 times. In example 2 the foreach loop runs only once. It does put all the lines of both files in $i at once.

It does not matter how many lines are in $file2 but if there are zero or 1 line in $File1 foreach thinks there is only one line.

Edit: When I add blank lines to $file1 everything runs smooth.

Comment: What is your powershell version? I figure you have 2.0. Does `$content = @(get-content $File1)` change your findings?

Comment: `$content = @(Get-Content $File1,$File2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read file into line delimeted array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574163/read-file-into-line-delimeted-array)

Comment: $content = @(get-content $File1) fixed it. Now everything gets sorted in the array correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Matt solved it in the comments.

Correct code to read the first file would be: `$content = @(get-content $File1)`